# Does metal rod makes it more difficult to swing than ropes?

Tags: kinematics, momentum

Imagine a piece of wooden plank suspensed by 2 metal rods instead of ropes, does it makes metal rod more difficult to swing? Feet must be off the ground at all times and no external forces is allowed. Please compare sitting and standing position too because I think it is easier to swing on the metal rod while standing on the wooden plank than sitting down and kicking hard.

[image]

Comment: One reason for swinging from ropes being easier when sitting might be because they conform to make any sitting position comfortable.

Comment: Not clear. There are several methods of pumping the swing, and methods often change from getting started to increasing the amplitude. Rods may be easier for one method and harder for another. What is your criterion for "easier"? Using less energy, or reaching a given amplitude faster?